# RenderScript Stopped Working in Android Lollilop

Tags: java, android, renderscript

I was developing an app in KitKat (4.4) and I recently flashed Lollipop on my device (5.1). My RenderScript Code seems that is has 'broken'. I mean it compiles fine, but when I launch the app it is not doing what it is supposed to do. I use it to do edge detection in parallel but it is not doing anything. Previously on KitKat I could see the edges. Now it renders what the camera sees, no effect, no edge detection.

Here is my Application Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="foo.bar"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!--uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /-->

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".LiveCameraActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my app gradle `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "foo.bar"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true //not applicable for rs targetapi 21+
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

And more or less this is how I call my RenderScript Code:

I have all my renderscript (.rs) files under the `rs` folder under `main`.

And in Java:

```
bmp = mTextureView.getBitmap();
bmpCopy = bmp.copy(bmp.getConfig(),true); //create a copy of the original
bitmapProcessor.processBmpEdgeDetect(bmp, bmpCopy); //I think this is where it breaks
mImageView.setImageBitmap(bmpCopy); // render result
```

Now `bitmapProcessor.processBmpEdgeDetect()` has this:

```
renderScriptEdgeDetectWrapper = new RenderScriptEdgeDetectWrapper(ctx);
renderScriptAvgOperWrapper.setInAllocation(bmp);
renderScriptAvgOperWrapper.setOutAllocation(bmpCopy);
renderScriptAvgOperWrapper.setScriptWidth(bmp.getWidth()-1);
renderScriptAvgOperWrapper.setScriptHeight(bmp.getHeight()-1);
renderScriptAvgOperWrapper.forEach_root();
```

And my `renderScriptAvgOperWrapper` is basically this:

```
public class RenderScriptEdgeDetectWrapper {

    private Allocation inAllocation;
    private Allocation outAllocation;
    private RenderScript rs;
    private ScriptC_edgedetect edgeDetectScript;
    private Context ctx;


    public RenderScriptEdgeDetectWrapper(Context context){
        ctx = context;
        rs = RenderScript.create(ctx);
        edgeDetectScript = new ScriptC_edgedetect(rs, ctx.getResources(), R.raw.edgedetect);
    };

    public void setInAllocation(Bitmap bmp){
        inAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs,bmp);
        edgeDetectScript.set_inPixels(inAllocation);
    };

    public void setOutAllocation(Bitmap bmp){
        outAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs,bmp);
    };

    public void setScriptWidth(int scriptWidth) {
        edgeDetectScript.set_width(scriptWidth);
    }

    public void setScriptHeight(int scriptHeight) {
        edgeDetectScript.set_height(scriptHeight);
    }

    public void forEach_root(){
        edgeDetectScript.forEach_root(inAllocation,outAllocation);
    }
}
```

It is just a simple wrapper.

Finally my renderScript `edgedetect.rs` file is this:

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(foo.bar)

rs_allocation inPixels;
int height;
int width;

void root(const uchar4 *in, uchar4 *out, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
    float3 pixel = convert_float4(in[0]).rgb;

    if(x==0 || x==width || y==0 || y==height){
        pixel.r = 0;
        pixel.g = 191;
        pixel.b = 255;
    }else{ //do image processing here

        float3 pixelNH = convert_float4(rsGetElementAt_uchar4(inPixels, x+1, y)).rgb;
        float3 pixelNV = convert_float4(rsGetElementAt_uchar4(inPixels, x, y+1)).rgb;

        int grayAvg = (pixel.r + pixel.g + pixel.b)/3;
        int grayAvgNH = (pixelNH.r + pixelNH.g + pixelNH.b)/3;
        int grayAvgNV = (pixelNV.r + pixelNV.g + pixelNV.b)/3;

        int edgeOperatorValue = 2*grayAvg - grayAvgNH - grayAvgNV;

        if(edgeOperatorValue < 0){
            edgeOperatorValue = -1 * edgeOperatorValue;
        };

        pixel.r = edgeOperatorValue;
        pixel.g = edgeOperatorValue;
        pixel.b = edgeOperatorValue;
    };

    out->xyz = convert_uchar3(pixel);
}
```

Now I do not understand why this code worked fine in KitKat but fails completely in Lollipop. If you could guide in what is wrong that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While you are calling forEach with renderScriptAvgOperWrapper, you are never actually copying the resulting output Allocation back into the bitmap you are drawing. You need to do an explicit "Allocation.copyTo(Bitmap)" operation after the forEach. The Allocation should be your output Allocation that you just wrote, and Bitmap is what you want to draw it to.

Comment: It can work if zero-copy is happening (i.e. the backing buffer is being shared). In that case, the copyTo() would do nothing. In the case where it is not zero-copy (i.e. USAGE_SHARED), you must copyTo() in order to update the buffer.